# iOS email and birthdate not getting from facebook

Tags: ios, iphone

The header:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UITextField *update;
    NSString *status;

}
@property (nonatomic, copy) IBOutlet NSString *status;
@end
```

.m File:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buttonPostStatus;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<FBGraphUser> loggedInUser;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *labelFirstName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *update;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *dob;
@property (strong,nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *profilename;

- (IBAction)postStatusUpdateClick:(UIButton *)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController


@synthesize buttonPostStatus = _buttonPostStatus;
@synthesize loggedInUser = _loggedInUser;
@synthesize labelFirstName = _labelFirstName;
@synthesize update;
@synthesize dob;
@synthesize profilename;


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    FBLoginView *loginview = [[FBLoginView alloc] init];

    loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 5);
    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setEdgesForExtendedLayout:)]) {
        loginview.frame = CGRectOffset(loginview.frame, 5, 25);
    }
    loginview.delegate = self;
    self.labelFirstName = nil;
    self.loggedInUser = nil;

    [self.view addSubview:loginview];

    [loginview sizeToFit];

    NSString *status = update.text;

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.buttonPostStatus = nil;


    [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {

    self.labelFirstName.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Hello %@ %@", user.first_name, user.last_name ];
    self.loggedInUser = user;
    self.dob.text= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Birthday- %@", user.birthday];
    NSLog(user.birthday);
    NSLog(self.labelFirstName.text);
    //NSLog(user.dob);

    }

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"FBLoginView encountered an error=%@", error);
}

- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
    // we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission
    if ([FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
        [FBSession.activeSession requestNewPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_actions"]
                                              defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                                            completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                                                if (!error) {
                                                    action();
                                                } else if (error.fberrorCategory != FBErrorCategoryUserCancelled){
                                                    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Permission denied"
                                                                                                        message:@"Unable to get permission to post"
                                                                                                       delegate:nil
                                                                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                                                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
                                                    [alertView show];
                                                }
                                            }];
    } else {
        action();
    }

}
- (IBAction)postStatusUpdateClick:(UIButton *)sender {

    NSURL *urlToShare = [NSURL URLWithString:@"htts.facebook.com/ios"];

    FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:urlToShare
                                                          name:@"Hello Facebook"
                                                       caption:nil
                                                   description:@"The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration."
                                                       picture:nil
                                                   clientState:nil
                                                       handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error) {
                                                           if (error) {
                                                               NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
                                                           } else {
                                                               NSLog(@"Success!");
                                                           }
                                                       }];

            [self performPublishAction:^{
                FBRequestConnection *connection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

                connection.errorBehavior = FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorReconnectSession
                | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorAlertUser
                | FBRequestConnectionErrorBehaviorRetry;

                [connection addRequest:[FBRequest requestForPostStatusUpdate:update.text]
                     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

                         [self showAlert:update.text result:result error:error];
                         self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = YES;
                     }];
                [connection start];

                self.buttonPostStatus.enabled = NO;
            }];
        }


- (void)showAlert:(NSString *)message
           result:(id)result
            error:(NSError *)error {

    NSString *alertMsg;
    NSString *alertTitle;
    if (error) {
        alertTitle = @"Error";
        if (error.fberrorUserMessage && FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
            alertTitle = nil;

        } else {
            // Otherwise, use a general "connection problem" message.
            alertMsg = @"Operation failed due to a connection problem, retry later.";
        }
    } else {
        NSDictionary *resultDict = (NSDictionary *)result;
        alertMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Successfully posted '%@'.", update.text];
        NSString *postId = [resultDict valueForKey:@"id"];
        if (!postId) {
            postId = [resultDict valueForKey:@"postId"];
        }
        if (postId) {
            alertMsg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\nPost ID: %@", alertMsg, postId];
        }
        alertTitle = @"Ho Gya!!";
    }

    if (alertTitle) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:alertTitle
                                                            message:alertMsg
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}

@end
```

I want to get the user information like username, email id, birthday etc.. whenever the user logs in.

I am trying to get the info of user by this code. Am I correct or not? If something is missing in this code, please provide some coding solution.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you are using? Are you getting incorrect output? Are you getting errors? What have you tried? I suggest you read these and edit your question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set **Permission** for that

```
loginview.readPermissions=@[@"email"];
```

Comment: no.. i'm not able to get any output through nslog..
earlier i could retrieve the username but i still cannot get the birthday or email.. plz help'